# React Native, react-native init, Warnings

Tags: react-native

I'm using MacOS High Sierra,

My npm version is

```
6.2.0
```

My node.js version is

```
v10.6.0
```

I installed the react-native-cli,

```
react-native-cli@2.0.1
```

When I do

```
react-native init AwesomeProject
```

I get the following warnings,

```
warning "react-native > metro-babel-register > 
@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining@7.0.0-beta.47" 
has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@7.0.0-beta.47".
warning "react-native > metro-babel-register > 
@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining > @babel/plugin- 
syntax-optional-chaining@7.0.0-beta.47" has unmet peer 
dependency "@babel/core@7.0.0-beta.47".
warning " > react-native@0.56.0" has unmet peer dependency 
"react@16.4.1".
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the issue, the problem is that there's [@babel/core](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@babel/core)
 and [babel-core](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-core) which are different packages...